# ESlint - restrict console.logs by specific text

Tags: javascript, eslint

i use vscode extension called turbo console log and sometimes console logs starts with 'tcl' left on the code.

**is there any way to restrict console.logs with specific text in their first argument?**

example:
`console.log('tcl: ', 'eslint')`